# Adding iOS @1x, @2x, @3x PER device, how to?

Tags: ios, swift, resolution, scaling, pixel

I recently asked a question about why we use the 3 different image types listed above, and got good/detailed responses.  It also lead me to question something else...

Assume I am working in XCode (with SWIFT) and have the three image sizes @1x, @2x, @3x for a particular say UIImage on an iPhone.  Now, I want it to look nice on iPad, so I add some scaling.  However, this will change the sizes of the 1x, 2x, 3x images I need for the iPad, so I need to make 3 more to compensate for that new size.  Now how will XCode differentiate between the two?  Do I need to check what size screen I am using and then choose the images?

I read that assets could help me, but that only deals with iPhone vs. iPad, what if I scale my images across iPhone 4, 5, 6 and iPad.  That's a lot of different sizes and @x images, and I read Apple doesn't like device checking so I'm not sure how that would happen.

I hope this makes sense.  I get the @1x, 2x, 3x per device, but if my app is being designed for universal device use, then how do I manage all of these different sizes in code for the proper device?

Comment: It sounds like you want a different size image for the same scale across different devices? You shouldn't need to do this really. A 2x image on the phone would be the same as a 2x image on the ipad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should use image asset catalog. It makes it almost too easy. Here is the definition Apple gives so you know it's not hearsay:

> Image sets: Used for most types of images, an image set contains all the versions, or representations, of an image that are necessary to support various devices and scale factors.

And it goes on further:

> Each set in an asset catalog has a name. You can use that name to programmatically load any individual image contained in the set. To load an image, call the platform specific class method, passing in the name of the set that contains the image. **The OS will load the image from the set that is most appropriate for the current scale factor**

So there really is not much for you to do. I don't know where you heard the opposite

[See Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Comment: Okay, so from what you are saying is that I can throw all my potential images with different resolutions in that particular set.  Then, I simply reference that set and the OS will pick the best one for that particular situation, so I don't have to do all of this device and compatibility checking.    I was under the impression that I had to include a reference to an exact image in each case, but it looks like it's more lenient than I had first thought...at least I think that's what you are saying.

Comment: @CodeMark22 that about sums it up

Answer (score -3):

You need to check the size of the biggest image, if you are using an iPad figure out the size of the UIImageView frame. For instance if it is 400*400pts then your image will be 1200*1200. Just use a single image. I don't think you need to include the @2x and @1x. The 1200*1200 covers your bases for the largest possible image and scaling down will still have plenty of pixels left over for the full @3x resolution on other devices and so on. This is how I understand it anyway. I also wondered this myself and only found @1x @2x @3x useful for things that I didn't scale up as the screen size increased such as some buttons.

Comment: Using lower resolution on low-resolution displays gives you better rendering performance.

Comment: Yes, I have made one app where I made a max size it would require, and on smaller devices it would scale it down and not lose any pixels.  But as Darko said I'm wondering if for larger apps this makes things a bit fragile and slow.  So far it seems to be fine as I only used it for a few buttons.  However, you never know as things get more complicated so I was looking for more of what is the standard way of doing things.